# execute_update pl/sql in jruby fails

Tags: oracle, plsql, jruby, oracle-call-interface

I am trying to connect to the oracle db using jdbc driver and that part works fine. After that I want to execute some pl/sql bolck and this is where I am having problem which seems to be syntactical. Can somebody please help me in fixing this? I tried to figure out but could not. Below is the code snippet.

```
   userlist = ['John', 'Sam', 'Lucia']

   $userlist.each do|usr|
   puts "Working on #{usr}"
   stmt = <<-EOF
       DECLARE
            CURSOR cur IS
                   SELECT sid, serial#
                   FROM v$session WHERE username = upper('#{usr}');

       BEGIN
                   FOR rec IN cur
                     LOOP
                       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER USER #{usr} IDENTIFIED BY chng';
                       dbms_output.put_line('Killing sessions which belong to #{usr}...');
                       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '''||session_rec.sid||','||session_rec.serial#'''';
                     END LOOP;
                   END;
       EOF

       #in the initialize method I established the connection and it is working fine.
       plsql_stmt = @conn.create_statement 
       plsql_stmt.execute_update(stmt)
   end
```

Error message:

```
   Working on John
   NativeException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 10, column 100:
   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "'" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   return returning <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <>
   and or like like2 like4 likec between into using || bulk
   member submultiset
   The symbol "*" was substituted for "'" to continue.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried executing the code in sqldeveloper?

Comment: I would `puts stmt` and inspect it. The error message suggests you have a misplaced apostrophe.

Comment: I am executing the code on linux box using putty.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Thanks for the suggestion to print out the query. I was missing '||' at the end of "Alter system kill" query. The correction is `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '''||session_rec.sid||','||session_rec.serial#||'''';`

Answer (score 0):

Refactor the big bad plsql into a plsql procedure and use https://github.com/rsim/ruby-plsql to call it from ruby

Answer (score 0):

That error message suggest that you have a SQL syntax error, specifically around an apostrophe. I would `puts stmt` and inspect it.